# UITableview中のcell描画の中で必要なくなった画像表示をキャンセルするには

Tags: swift, uitableview

Xcode 7.3を使ってSwiftプログラミングを行っています。

```
func tableView(table: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? CustomTableViewCell

        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: (fileArray[indexPath.row] as? String)!+".jpg")!
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(req, queue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){(res, data, err) in
            let img = UIImage(data:data!)
            cell!.thumb.image = img
        }
```

のようにしてセルの中に画像(cell.thumb.image)を表示しているのですが、高速にスクロールさせた場合、画像の読み込み及び表示が追いつかなく、停止した際にサムネイルがパタパタと切り替わります。

表示の必要がない画像（過ぎ去った）は読み込み、または表示をキャンセルすることはできないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest()`はキャンセル処理をサポートしていません。`NSURLConnection`はキャンセル可能なAPIも備えていますが、NSURLConnectionの使用はiOS 9から非推奨になっているので、代わりの新しいAPIである`NSURLSession`または`NSURLSession`を利用したライブラリ（Alamofireなど）を利用しましょう。

画像のダウンロードですので、`NSURLSession`から`NSURLSessionDataTask`を作成します。後ほど、セルが非表示（画面外）になった際にはキャンセルできるように、`NSURLSessionDataTask`は保持しておきます。

下記の例では`downloadTasksPerURL`というディクショナリを用いてURLをキーにして保持することにします。
また、セルが非表示になった際にキャンセルするために`NSURLSessionDataTask`を特定できるように、セルに画像のURLを持たせるようにしています。

セルが画面外に出る際には、`tableView(_:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)`というデリゲートメソッドが呼ばれますので、そのタイミングで該当の`NSURLSessionDataTask`を`cancel()`メソッドでキャンセルします。

下記はコードの例です。

```
...
var downloadTasksPerURL = [NSURL: NSURLSessionTask]()
...

func tableView(table: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    let imageURL = ...

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: imageURL)) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            return
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)!
            cell!.thumb.image = image
        }
    }

    cell.imageURL = imageURL
    downloadTasksPerURL[imageURL] = task

    task.resume()

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let task = downloadTasksPerURL[cell.imageURL] {
        task.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: 高速にリスト(UITableView)を下に移動させるとdataが(NSData?)nilになり、エラーで止まります。imageURLで指定された画像はあるのですが。何が原因かわかりますか？

Comment: @Ubunkun ちょっとおっしゃってる意味がよくわからないです。エラーで止まるというのはクラッシュするということですか？それはどこで起こりますか？「ima‌​geURLで指定された画像」はあるというのは、サーバー側にはあってブラウザなどで見ると確認できるけど、なぜかdataにはnilが入っているということですか？

Comment: クラッシュします。これは、let image = UIImage(data: data!)! で発生します。dataがnilです。またサーバ側にあってブラウザで見ると画像は確認できます。しかし、なぜかdataにはnilが入っています。これはUITableviewをスクロール（下に）するとほぼ100%で発生(nilになるケース)します。

Comment: たぶんサーバ側でリミットがかけてあるんじゃないですか。問題の切り分けのために、同時に複数のリクエストを送ってみたり、レスポンスコードやエラーオブジェクトに何か入ってないかどうかなどを調べてみたらいかがでしょうか。

Comment: サーバ側は私自身が設定（設置）したサーバで、私一人のアクセスしかなく特にリミットかけていません。

Comment: なるほど。私からはそれ以上は分かりません。まず問題を切り分けてみましょう。キャンセル処理をなくしてみると変わるんじゃないかとも思います。

Comment: キャンセル処理を削除したらdataがnilになることは無くなりました（クラッシュがなくなりました）。taskをキャンセルするとdataがなぜnilになることがあるのでしょうか？

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44114/discussion-between-kishikawa-katsumi-and-ubunkun)しましょう。